# Ant Design - select - OnPopupScroll - React.js

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown, antd, infinite-scroll

```html
                                    <Select
                                      showSearch
                                      filterOption={(input, option) => {
                                        if (option.props.children != undefined) {
                                          return (
                                            option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                                          )
                                        }
                                      }
                                      }
                                      name="user"
                                      placeholder="Select User"
                                      id="user"
                                      onChange={e =>
                                        this.handleChange("user", e)
                                      }
                                      onPopupScroll = {this.loadMore}
                                      className="customSelectTemplate"
                                      disabled={this.state.editEnabled}
                                    >
                                      <Option value="">Select</Option>
                                      {this.state.userList &&
                                        this.state.userList.map(userList => (
                                          userList && userList.userNumber != null &&
                                          <Option value={userList.userNumber}>
                                            {userList.name}
                                          </Option>
                                        ))}
                                        {this.state.loadingState == true ? 
                                        <Option value="">Loading .....</Option>
                                        : ""}
                                    </Select>
```

I have designed a page using react. I need to implement infinite scrolling in an ant dropdown. So I am using the onPopupScroll function of antd select to call API to load more data to the dropdown. But i am facing performance issue in the dropdown. The scrollbar is not working properly. I cant able to drag the scrollbar to the end of the options. It is very slow. Has someone faced this issues? How can I fix this?

```html
loadMore = ( e) => {
    this.setState({ loadingState: true });
    e.persist (); 
     const {target} = e; 
     if (target.scrollTop + target.offsetHeight === target.scrollHeight) { 
       // API call (to load more data..........)
    }
   
  }
```

Comment: can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem after 2 years...

This is my case and it works fine, You can also help me get better.
[github HomePage](https://github.com/xunziheng/antd-debounce-select)

```
     onPopupScroll={async (e: any) => {
        const { target } = e;
        if (
          (target as any).scrollTop + (target as any).offsetHeight ===
          (target as any).scrollHeight
        ) {
          // if not load all;
          if (options.length < total) {
            setHasContentLoading(true);
            const page: Page = {
              // (currentPage - 1 + 1) * pageSize;
              offset: currentPage * pageSize,
              limit: pageSize,
            };
            await fetchOptions(searchValue, page).then((newOptions) => {
              setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
              options.push(...newOptions);
              setOptions(options);
              setHasContentLoading(false);
            });
          }
        }
      }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why would you use this

```
e.persist();
```

But [here](https://codepen.io/abucraft/pen/dLWRZp) is a decent solution, I used earlier with a paginated api, to load data in the Select component.